# Python: How can i find new folders/directories created in last hour in a specific directory in Linux

Tags: python, linux, bash

i am trying to write a python program which calls a bash script to run on new data in the directory.

I have several hundred sub-directories in my directory. Every hour few sub directories are generated. I am trying to get into these new sub-directories and run my script on the data inside it.

Lets say path for my directory is /data1/realtime:

In directory 'realtime' there are new sub-directories generated every hour. How can i know new sub-dir generated every hour and get inside each one of those one by one..?

Many Thanks!!

yash

Comment: This is a poor method. Just because a sub-directory is created doesn't mean it has all the files you expect, and just because a file exists does not mean that it is written completely by the asynchronous process. You should look at the `inotifywait`suite of shell commands.

Comment: Thank You msw for your response. I am just worried to use bash here as i will perform some other processing in python as well, before calling bash script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`find`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/find) command (in your shell):

```
find /data1/realtime -mmin -60 -type d
```

It will print all directories that has been created or that has had files or subdirectories added, removed or renamed the last 60 minutes.

You can of course call this from Python's [`subprocess` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) if needed, but since you are using bash already, maybe you can use it in the bash script directly?

Here's how to call find using `subprocess`:

```
import subprocess
directories = subprocess.check_output(
    ['find', '/data1/realtime', '-type', 'd', '-mmin', '-60']
).splitlines()
# directories content: ['/data1/realtime/dir1000', ...]
```

This might catch directories that are in the process of being created, like msw said in the comments, so if you want to find directories that are created the last hour but not more recently than 5 minutes ago, you can add another test to `find`:

```
find /data1/realtime -mmin -60 -mmin +5 -type d
```

Just to see how this works, here's a bash session:

```
$ find --version
find (GNU findutils) 4.4.2
...
$ mkdir /tmp/test
$ cd /tmp/test
$ date 
Mon Feb  9 21:27:00 CET 2015
$ touch a
$ touch -t 02092100 b  # 27 minutes ago
$ touch -t 02082100 c  # yesterday
$ ls -alh
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  2 andre andre 100 Feb  9 21:27 .
drwxrwxrwt 24 root  root  520 Feb  9 21:26 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 andre andre   0 Feb  9 21:27 a
-rw-r--r--  1 andre andre   0 Feb  9 21:00 b
-rw-r--r--  1 andre andre   0 Feb  8 21:00 c
$ find . -mmin -60 -mmin +5
./b
```

As expected, the newly created file (a) and the file from yesterday (c) are excluded, but the file that was updated 27 minutes ago (b) is included. This should work if you are

Comment: Thank you Andre´ Laszlo for your detailed response. I tried the above script but when i couldn't add two tests in one subprocess..

 ['find', '/data1/realtime', '-type', 'd', '-mmin', '-60', '-type', 'd', '-mmin', '+5']

but this didnt work ..

Comment: Okay, it works for me. Did you get an error message or just an empty result? I'm adding an example above.

Comment: Well I am trying this in python using subprocess. it wasnt working for me there .. i am very new to python and bash programming both..

Comment: Did you get an exception? Does it work if you try it in the shell (bash)?

Comment: Its working fine in shell(bash). but in subprocess its gives an error

Comment: Ok, cool. That narrows it down a bit I think! What's the error/exception? If `find` spews out an error you should be able to find it just before the stack trace ("CalledProcessError...").

Comment: directories = subprocess.check_output(
    ['find', '/Users/sdb99/Desktop', '-type', 'd', '-mmin', '-60', '-type', 'd', '-mmin', '+5']
).splitlines()


surprisingly its not giving me any error ... but not listing new folders created in last one hour which were generated before last 5 mins. WIthout the additional test it works perfect bt not now..

Comment: Ok, that sounds odd, especially if it's working in the shell. Maybe that can be a new question (post code) since we have diverged from your original question a bit now.

Comment: Thank you @Andre´ Laszlo! this find command in shell gives me all the sub directories created in past hour as well. How can know only directories created in past hour?

Comment: I'm glad you got it working! :) I'm not sure I understand your question - do you mean directories but not subdirectories created the last hour?

Comment: If this is the case, and you are searching in `/a`, and you get the matches `/a/b`, `/a/b/c` and `/a/b/d` - give find the `-maxdepth` argument. `-maxdepth 1` will only look in the directory you said, `-maxdepth 2` will look one level deeper and so on.

Comment: ´Laszlo - Big thanks buddy. Yes this works perfect. I had spent 3 hours finding solution to this but couldn't. very grateful.

Comment: ´ Laszlo: i getting following error when i run the above command on my linux terminal : " find: warning: you have specified the -maxdepth option after a non-option argument -type, but options are not positional (-maxdepth affects tests specified before it as well as those specified after it).  Please specify options before other arguments. "

Comment: Try putting the `-maxdepth` arg before the tests.

Comment: Thank you @Andre´Laszlo for quick response! i dont know if that will work. here is the syntax i am talking about    directories = subprocess.check_output(
    ['find', '/Users/sdb99/Desktop/dicom', '-maxdepth', '1', '-type', 'd', '-mmin', '-5', '-type', 'd', '-mmin', '+1',
     '-maxdepth', '1']
).splitlines()

Comment: You have the `-maxdepth` argument twice. Remove the last one and it should work. :-)

Answer (score 3):

You can uses os.listdir sets to compare:

```
import  os
path = "."
prev = [d for d in os.listdir(".") if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(path,d))]
os.mkdir("foo")

curr = [d for d in os.listdir(".") if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(path,d))]
new = set([d for d in os.listdir(".") if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(path,d))]).difference(prev)

for d in new:
   print(new)
```

Comment: but [race conditions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition#Software) since your script cannot determine if the dictionaries and files that are new are also complete

Comment: @msw, if the OP is going to run the script on the hour when the directories are created yes there may be an issue, from my understanding of the question the directories are created every  hour if at all so running the script slightly delayed I doubt there will be any race conditions. If the OP wants realtime updates then they can use inotifywait, I was going to add it originally but that requires the package to be installed so not a general solution.